# OpenTK file not found exception

Tags: c#, opengl, filenotfoundexception, opentk, file-not-found

I installed OpenTK using nuget package manager, [used this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztyoJfyOz5k&t=273s) even though it is old and my program seemed to be working but then [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KSmu.png).

"Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor" means "System cannot find the specified file".

Some file is missing but I don't know how to re-add it or did I not install OpenTK correctly? OpenTK is colored like it is supposed to. I don't know what can I do to fix this issue, please help me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, turns outyou can manually add the missing specified file by:

- going to nuget package manager,
- typing in Install-Package Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents -Version 4.7.0
- and when I fixed that it said System.Drawing.Common was missing too so you might want to type Install-Package System.Drawing.Common -Version 4.7.0 to fix it
  this worked for me and I found both of those on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org).